# Failed to parse multipart servlet request; Stream ended unexpectedly

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot.

I am trying to create Request with 'multipart/mixed' content type.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/testData", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/mixed",headers = {"boundary={boundaryName}"})
public String loadTestData(@PathVariable("boundaryName") String boundaryName) {
    return "OK";
}
```

I want data to be proccessed like below

```
—badifdkfinefdi
content-Type: application/json

{ 
text:testdata
}
--badifdkfinefdi
content-Type: application/octet-stream

Mddi,difd,dfdfd
--badifdkfinefdi--
```

I am getting error like this -

> "message": "Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly",

Any suggestions??

Comment: I have the same issue while sending json & csv files to my spring boot application via jmeter.

Comment: any solutions ?